# Difference between unnest() in SELECT vs unnest() in FROM on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, set-returning-functions

I want the lexemes of a tsvector array placed in a column, one per row.  I can first unnest the array and then the resulting tsvectors with:

```
SELECT (unnest(unnest(my_array))).lexeme
FROM my_table
WHERE id = 1;
```

which gives:

```
lexeme  
----------
foo
bar
baz
...
```

I noticed, however, that if I try to do the same in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT lexeme
FROM unnest(
    (SELECT unnest(my_array) FROM my_table WHERE id = 1)
);
```

I get:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

So, I end up doing this:

```
SELECT lexeme
FROM (
    SELECT (unnest(col1)).lexeme
    FROM (
        SELECT unnest(my_array) 
        FROM my_table 
        WHERE id = 1 
    ) AS t(col1)
) AS t2;
```

And I get the original result.  But this is verbose.  So, I'd like to know:

1. Why does unnest() require a single input row in the FROM clause, but doesn't in the SELECT clause?
2. Is there a more concise, less convoluted way than my code, to get the column of lexemes in the FROM clause?
3. Is there a difference in performance between unnesting in the SELECT clause, versus doing it in the FROM clause?

Comment: Possibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/23004157/14868997. You should favour two `LATERAL unnest` clauses over using them in the `select`

Comment: @Charlieface It's very relevant.  It's the answer to question 2:  `SELECT lexeme                        
FROM my_table, unnest(array_column) AS vector, unnest(vector)
WHERE product_id = 1;`  If you post it as an answer, I will mark it accepted.  Many thanks.  Now only questions 1 and 3 remain for the sake of clarification.

Comment: @ARX: question #1 is not really related to `unnest`.  Consider `select (select 1 union select 2)` which would fail with the same error message (_more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really supposed to use set-returning operators in the `select`, even though PostgreSQL allows it.

It's much better to place them in the `from` and use a `lateral` join

```sql
SELECT lexeme
FROM my_table t,
  lateral unnest(array_column) AS vector,
  lateral unnest(vector)
WHERE t.product_id = 1;
```